# ASP.NET Core project using openId connect with Okta and a secondary create account from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, okta

So Im making an app in asp.net mvc core and can't figure out how to do something.
So I currently have openId connect sign on with Okta. When the application starts up users need to sign in through the okta platform before they have access. The problem is that the application is going to try to match the email passed in by okta to an athlete, from a database. (The athlete object in the database also uses the email).

What I'm trying to do is create a case for when the application can't match the okta email to the database email (meaning that while they are part of the okta organization group that allowed into the application they haven't signed up as an athlete yet). Right now this case the application wouldn't let the user add any activities.

So what I want to do is after the Okta sign in is to have a secondary check that the okta user has created an athlete entity and if they haven't make them create one before they can access the rest of the application and its functions

I tried changing the startup.cs file but I can't get it to work, this is the part I have working with just the okta login stuff. I've tried looking online but I can't find any good resources for this

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultScheme = 
 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "okta";
   })
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
                    
    })
               
    //let users sign in with okta account
    .AddOpenIdConnect("okta", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = Configuration["Okta:CallbackPath"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    });
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do what I want? I'd really appreciate ideas or maybe a resource.

Comment: For me, it sounds like you need to configure user provisioning. If so, did you have a look at the SCIM protocol?